# Как смерджить два репозитория, если один является частью другого?

Tags: git

Есть два репозитория.
В одном такая структура -

```
project_1
├── parent_package
│   ├── file_1
│   ├── file_2
│   ├── file_3
│   └── file_4
└── parent_package_2
    └── file_1
```

Во втором -

```
parent_package
├── file_1
├── file_2
├── file_3
└── file_4
```

Задача смерджить parent_package первого и второго.
Собственно вопрос - как?

Вопрос решит также способ, позволяющий создать еще один реп, состоящий только из parent_package первого проекта с историей коммитов только этой директории.
Спасибо!

Comment: Используется git submodules - да или нет?

Comment: Увы, но нет, не используется

Comment: Поступило предложение смерджить руками, PyCharm вроде умеет в "compare".
Если нет явно более элегантного решения, окей - смерджу руками.

Comment: Как появились файлы в `parent_package` в обоих репах? Копированием файлов, а затем это закомитили в каждом репо отдельно, и `parent_package` начали развиваться отдельно, все верно?

Comment: Именно. @TotalPusher

Comment: Вместо форка провернули именно это.

Comment: Через git pull / push / merge такое не провернуть, так как это разные репозитории. Могу предложить сделать патч с одно репо, и применить его на второй репо. Патч - это по сути diff - файл, когда вы делаете `git diff` - вы и видите это. Можно сделать такой патч из нескольких коммитов, и применить его через git apply. Затем разрулить конфликты и закоммитить. История изменений файлов, конечно, не перенесется - будет только вот этот коммит. Если нужна история - несколько патчей, по одному на коммит. Также можно снести каталог и начать использовать git submodules